# json inner objects without an array

Tags: json, children

I've looked for a solution but keep coming up short.  I have the following json:

```
{
   "objects" : 
   {
      "a" : 
      {
         "a1" : { "value1" : "1" }
         "a2" : { "value2" : "2" }
      }, 
      "b" :
      {
         "b1" : { "value1" : "1" }
         "b2" : { "value2" : "2" }
      }
   }
}
```

So (assuming this is represented in the var jsonObject) if I know all of the object names, getting the value1 from a1 would be:

```
jsonObject.objects.a.a1.value1
```

The problem I'm running into is that I don't know the names of the inner objects.  It could be

```
{
   "objects" : 
   {
      "ax7634" : 
      {
         "a1" : { "value1" : "1" }
         "a2" : { "value2" : "2" }
      }, 
      "b78tgf" :
      {
         "b1" : { "value1" : "1" }
         "b2" : { "value2" : "2" }
      }
   }
}
```

I would say that this is poorly formed JSON data, and that **objects** should be an array.  But I can only play with the hand I'm dealt.  So my question is, if I don't know the inner objects name, is there a way to "discover" them or to reference them?  Is there a .child(n) method or some such that will give me the nth child?

Comment: is this java? then tag it so.

Comment: The keys won't have a guaranteed order, so you'll have to get all the keys, sort them, and then get the `n`th one.

Comment: Yea, I don't mind what order they come in; if I can access them then I can sort them.  I just can't figure out how to access them since I don't know their names and they aren't in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a for in loop

```
for(var key in objects){
    if (objects.hasOwnProperty(key)){
       objects[key]; // ax7364 in first iteration
    }
}
```